# Problem importing FastAPI spec into Postman

Tags: postman, openapi, fastapi

Trying to test my FastAPI project in Postman. It automatically generates an OpenAPI spec as a JSON file at `http://localhost:8000/openapi.json` on my machine. When I try to import this link in Postman, it gets hung up at this screen:

[image: postman_import_modal]

When I press the import button I get no error messages and nothing happens no matter how long I wait. I've verified that the JSON file at that URL is valid by pasting its contents into the "Raw Text" import method, which produces a new Postman collection as soon as I hit the "Import" button.

Comment: I believe there's an open issue for this and is being worked on (exposing the issue in the import ) if you select it as just the Collection, it will import. You would need to manually create an API with that schema in the API builder UI.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I checked their github issues page and found it here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8542